# VT-x not available in Windows 10 Pro even though i5-6400 CPU supports VT-X

Tags: windows-10, cpu, virtualization, intel-core-i5, vt-x

I have an Intel Core [i5-6400](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/core_i5/i5-6400) CPU installed on a ASUS Z-170A mainboard. 
According to the documentation of my [CPU](https://ark.intel.com/products/88185/Intel-Core-i5-6400-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3-30-GHz-), this CPU supports Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-X) and it is [listed as compatible with HAXM for Android](https://ark.intel.com/Search/FeatureFilter?productType=processors&ExtendedPageTables=true).  I have Windows 10 Pro (64-bit build 1803) and VT-x is **enabled** in BIOS settings, and Memory Integrity is **disabled** in Windows Defender.
I could not run virtual machines in VMWARE since it prompts for error:

> VMware Workstation and Device/Credential Guard are not compatible.
>   VMware Workstation can be run after disabling Device/Credential Guard.

However, when I use [Intel(R) Processor Identification Utility](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005651/processors.html), it reports that my CPU does not support VT-X. This prevents installing HAXM for Android.  How do I resolve this?

[image: Screenshot from Intel(R) Processor Identification Utility]

Comment: What security software do you have installed?  Edit your question to include this vital required information.  I assume you have already installed Hyper-V, which by default, is required for the Android emulator you plan on using.

Comment: Have you enabled VT-x in the BIOS? Asus defaults is "disabled".

Comment: Other folks with this issue have found resolution by going into BIOS Setup, disabling VT-x, saving the Setup change, turning the PC off, rebooting, going back into BIOS Setup, and turning it back on and saving the change again. Please try that and report the result by clicking on `edit` above at left, and adding that into your original post.

Comment: @K7AAY I should thank for your follow up. finally this problem resolved

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately VMWare prompt and its resolution document was misleading and not explanatory enough to help me.

To enable VT-x besides of enabling it in BIOS, uses should [Disable Windows Defender Credential Guard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/credential-guard/credential-guard-manage)  as below:

1. Run `gpedit.msc` and then go to:

`Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Device Guard -> Turn on Virtualization Based Security`

and select `Disabled` option.

2. Then run `regedit` and delete these keys if they are present in registery:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA\LsaCfgFlags
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceGuard\EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceGuard\RequirePlatformSecurityFeatures

3. Execute `cmd` as administrator and run below command to enable NX bit:

> bcdedit.exe /set {current} nx AlwaysOn

4. For me, the magic part was this. run `regedit` and in folder:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios\HypervisorEnforcedCodeIntegrity

set `Enabled` to  0.

Here is the result:
[image]

P.S. Great thanks to Ulises2k for his/her answer at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8004c3bd-7d57-40ce-93de-0b1a6babd64c/how-i-can-disable-credential-guard?forum=win10itprovirt which helped me for part 4 of this answer.

Comment: I really hate the way only one hypervisor can be used on a given system. I can understand why it is that way, but still its a real pain.

Comment: @FrankThomas I have no technical idea why this happens, but Microsoft usually do same things for other products once a while. One the time of windows XP, it was IE and Netscape navigator, once it was Media Player and other players. It might the be it came to the time that VMWare and Hypervisor are going to challenge each other.