# enabling intel vt-x virtualiziation in asus motherboard

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, centos, virtualization

motherboard specs:

```
asus strix h370-f
```

https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-H370-I-GAMING/specifications/

```
cpu: intel i7-8700 non k
```

I am trying to work with virtual box, vmware etc 
and i get this message:

[image: when trying to run centos on workstation]

I tried 32 bit and 62 bit centos, didn't work

system information:

[image: part 1]
[image: part 2]

bios shot - shows it is supported no place to enable

[image: bios shows the problem]

Please help I can't seem to figure it out 
it only says supported but no option to choose enabled 
how do I fix this ?

Comment: You already have it enabled which means you either have Hyper-V installed or Core Isolation enabled.

Comment: So what do I need to do from here ?

Comment: You should be able to run a 32-bit OS within a VM regardless.  You only need VT-x enabled to run a 64-bit OS within the VM.  Solution is either determine what incompatible application you have installed or verify if Core Isolation is disabled

Comment: How do i verify if core isolation is disabled ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: https://superuser.com/questions/1366264/vt-x-not-available-in-windows-10-pro-even-though-i5-6400-cpu-supports-vt-x

Comment: You will have to do the proper research.  It’s well documented.  Update your question once you can supply the required information needed to answer your question

Comment: take a look at this video, there may be a second place you need to enable VT-D: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Yp_qJxEkkg