# Surface Book and VT-x

Tags: virtualization, microsoft-surface, hardware-virtualization

I have the Surface Book with i7-6600U processor. It has to support VT-x, however, Intel processor identification utility says it does not.

What I tried to do in order to remove this issue:

1. All the steps from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1366264/vt-x-not-available-in-windows-10-pro-even-though-i5-6400-cpu-supports-vt-x?rq=1).
2. Recovery of the Surface Book using recovery image from the Microsoft web-site, so that the laptop is free from possible apps that use Hyper-V (by the way, Hyper-V is disabled).

VT-x still does not work.

On another SB that I own the problem is absent. What can be a reason for this?

Comment: Have you enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: @essjae : Surface  Book has UEFI, and there is no such the option.

Comment: ok, semantics, but you can still get into the UEFI settings:  https://surfacetip.com/configuring-surface-book-uefi-bios-settings/

Comment: @essjae : there is nothing to do with VT-x.

Comment: Ok, if you run "systeminfo" from a PS/CMD prompt, what's under the "Hyper-V requirements" setting at the end?  Everything should report "yes"  Also, what version of Windows 10 do you have? Home/Pro/Ent? Build number?

Comment: @essjae : it turned out that the virtualization-based security was enabled (which was displayed in system information). After disabling it everything goes perfect.